# Taking the limit of a complex sine function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Want to show $$\lim_{z\to\ 0} sin|z|/z$$, so far I let $$f(z)=sin|z|$$ then I used the Cauchy-Riemann equations to find the set A in which f is analytic, thus $$u_x=cos|z|*x/|z|,u_y=cos|z|*y/|z|,v_x=0,v_y=0$$ Then by the criterion we have $$cos|z|*x/|z|=0,cos|z|*y/|z|=0 \implies x=0 \intertext{or} y=0 \implies y=\pi /2+k\pi \intertext{or} x=\pi /2+k\pi$$ respectively. Thus f is analytic on $$\mathbb{C}-({x=0 \intertext{or} y=0 \implies y=\pi /2+k\pi \intertext{or} x=\pi /2+k\pi}) $$ Therefore the derivative of f exists, then when you take the limit from z to $$0$$ we get $$0$$. Did I miss something? The solution in the book states that it does not exist

Answer (score 1):

The book is correct - it does not exist. To see this, write 
$$ {\sin |z| \over z } = {\sin |z| \over |z| } \cdot { |z| \over z }.$$
We know that $\lim_{z\to 0} \sin |z|/ |z| =1$, so that if the LHS had a limit, so would $|z|/z$ - but it does not.

Edit: $|z|/z = e^{i\theta}$, for some $\theta$. So the value of the wannabe limit would depend on the choice of $\theta$ - i.e., for instance of a line through $0$ one used to approach $0$. Hence, there is no unique value for a would-be limit, and so the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Oh I just realized a silly mistake, we have a case where x=o AND/OR y=0, thus f is not analytic on the set A in which this occurs thus when z approaches 0, it does not exist

Comment: Even without that, being analytic is not the principal issue. After all $z \mapsto \sin |z|$ is continuous on the complex plane, and tends to $0$ as $z$ tends to $0$. The issue is more a 'cal one' style problem: you have a 'wannabe' limit of the form '0/0' - sometimes it exists, sometimes it doesn't.